# I want to stop mediaplayer when home button is pressed

Tags: android, background, media-player, playing

When I am out of my app (when pressed home button or back button), the music keeps playing in the background. How can I stop it?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

MediaPlayer ourSong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.girissong);
    ourSong.start();

    // codes

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // some code

         }

         }

}
```

I made this code and it should stop when I go to next class and the next song will start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the below two methods in you class for stopping the Music play while navigating to other Screens and Home button respectively....

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
   super.onPause();
   if(ourSong.isPlaying())
   ourSong.stop();
   else
   return;
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
   super.onStop();
  if(ourSong.isPlaying())
    ourSong.stop();
  else
   return;
}
```

Comment: I did that and it forces to close

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION : main
java.lang.Runtimeexception:unable to pause activity(com.example.MainActivity). java.langI11 Legal.state.exception

Comment: 12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.barbaryaman/com.example.barbaryaman.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3016)
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: 12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2971)
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949)
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)

Comment: 12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1245)
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: 12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 13:21:49.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1186): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: forgot to call super.onPause() and super.onStop() methods. I have edited the answer. Please use that. Now wont get the error

Comment: i still got errors, i guess i will try using exit button. thanks for your help but didnt work for me , i give up :)

Comment: I dont know where u r getting errors.. Dont give up man... actually what i understood is - 1. while clicking the HOME and 2. While navigating to other screens the music is not stopping... thats it right? So use onPause() and onStop() for HOME and other screens respectively...

Comment: it stops when i go to other screen because i use ourSong.release();
but it doesnt stop when i press home

Comment: I guess i was putting that code in a wrong place so i was getting errors, i did it right at the bottom of my code and it worked fine now . thanks a lot , you are master :)

Answer (score 4):

Override the onPause method of the activity and call stop on the MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 2):

Check out what you want to do on [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). 
Example:

```
protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();

     ourSong.stop();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to override **onKeyDown()** method and check the **keyevent** if it is home key or back button methong, and inside this method stop your media player object then release it. 
**mp.stop();
mp.release();**

Answer (score 1):

you should probably put

```
if (player != null && player.isPlaying()) {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    player = null;
}
```

inside your onStop(), or onDestroy() method of your activity also.

If you put it in `onStop()` the audio would stop when the home button is pressed(or anytime another activity takes over phone rings perhaps).

If you put it in `onDestroy()` it would keep playing until the system needs the resources that your application is using. Either way it is a good idea so that your app is not holding on the the MediaPlayer resources incase the user doesn't hit the stop button for whatever reason.

Comment: I think it would be better to use onPause().

Comment: but it says "player can not be resolved", should i add local variable or field?